# How to apply IDFT and noise to a signal array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signals, signal-processing

So I'm currently making a python program that involves making a synthetic ecg signal, first we have to make an rr tachogram, which I did, here's the code

```
#import necessary modules to start the program
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Create standard deviation variables, which are c1 and c2, t1 and t2 have the same value as hf and lf
c1 = 0.01
c2 = 0.01
#N = NRR which is 256, and is the total amount of data
tau1 = np.sqrt(0.056)
tau2 = np.sqrt(0.076)
N = 256
f1 = 0.1
f2 = 0.25
Nrr= 256
lf = 0.056
hf = 0.076
#ratio also has the equation of  lf/hf
ratio = lf/hf

#declare imaginary numbers
S_real = np.zeros(1000)
S_imaj = np.zeros(1000)
MagIDFT = np.zeros(1000)
#the arrays(lists) that will be used for plotting the signal
S = []
F = []

#we make this into a gauss series function
def SF_gauss_series():
  #The main S(F) series that is according to the bimodal spectrum equation
  for i in range(N):
    f = i/Nrr
    #In the mirroring part, we use the signal mirroring equation, x(t) -> x(t+1) -> x(-t+1)
    s = (tau1**2/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*c1**2)))*np.exp(-(f-f1)**2/(2*c1**2)) + \
    (tau2**2/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*c2**2)))*np.exp(-(f-f2)**2/(2*c2**2))     + \
    (tau1**2/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*c1**2)))*np.exp(-(f-1+f1)**2/(2*c1**2))   + \
    (tau2**2/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*c2**2)))*np.exp(-(f-1+f2)**2/(2*c2**2))
    #As you can see we have 4 signals, we the the last 2 signals, inverted.
    #After sequencing the f and s variables, 
    #We use the append() function and move it the F and S array
    F.append(f)
    S.append(s)
SF_gauss_series()

#Here, we utilize matplotlib as plt, and start plotting the current RSA and Mayer Signals
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
#this part to plot the array
plt.plot(F,S, color='orange')
#labeling and naming code
plt.xlabel('Freq. (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('power (sec*2/Hz)')
plt.title("Post-Mirrored Mayer and RSA Waves")
#final show() function to display the graph
plt.show()
```

Now the question is, how do i apply IDFT to it?(Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform) and give noise to the signal? I know that to apply noise is that you can use np.random() function, but I have no idea how to IDFT it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the inverse DFT to some signal `S` (as an array) you can apply

```
FS = np.fft.ifft(S)
```

This is documented in [`np.fft.ifft`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html).

In case you are interested in the purely real signal you can apply e.g. extract the real part using `np.real` or use the the aboslute value `np.abs` - but if you constructed the signal to be real and the imaginary parts are just artefacts of the floating point math, you can also consider using [`numpy.real_if_close`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.real_if_close.html#numpy.real_if_close) to avoid accidentally discarding large imaginary values that might appear if the input might not actually represent a real signal.